# add the osmdroid library via Android Studio (Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am quite new to mobile development and try to develop a simple android app. For my project I need OSM (open street map or more accurate osmdroid. I tried to follow these instructions: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle but unfortunately That did not work for me. I think I just inserted the code in a wrong place.  [image]

Thats the place where it is now. Here is the code which is inside the "build.gradle (:app)":

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(6.1.6)'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:(6.1.6)'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:(6.1.6)'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:(6.1.6)'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

If I try to sync this is the error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(6.1.6).
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:(6.1.6).
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:(6.1.6).
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:(6.1.6).
     Required by:
         project :app

 * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should remove the brackets from library version
so instead of this

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(6.1.6)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:(6.1.6)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:(6.1.6)'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:(6.1.6)'
```

write this

```
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:6.1.6'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-geopackage:6.1.6'
```